# why does my notify() not wake a waiting thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple multithreaded algorithm designed to load a series of files in a background thread, and have a JPanel display the first image as soon as it is done loading.  In the constructor of the JPanel, I start the loader, then wait on the list of images, as follows:

```
//MyPanel.java
public ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
int frame;    

public MyPanel(String dir){
    Thread loader = new thread (new Loader(dir, this));
    loader.start();

    frame = 0;
    //miscellaneous stuff

    synchronized(images){
        while (images.isEmpty()){
            images.wait();
        }
    }

    this.setPrefferedSize(new Dimension(800,800));
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g)

    g.drawImage(images.get(frame), 0, 0, 800, 800, null);
}
```

my Loader thread looks like this:

```
//Loader.java
String dir;
MyPanel caller;

public Loader(String dir, MyPanel caller){
    this.dir = dir;
    this.caller = caller;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    File dirFile = new File(dir);
    File[] files = dirFile.listFiles();
    Arrays.sort(files);

    for (File f : files) {
        try {
            synchronized (caller.images) {
                BufferedImage buffImage = ImageIO.read(f);
                caller.images.add(buffImage);
                caller.images.notifyAll();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that execution passes through `notifyAll()` several times (usually >20) before the calling thread wakes up and displays the image in the frame.  I have also verified that the images object is in fact the same object as the one being waited on.  I have attempted adding a `yield()`, but that did not help.  why does the call to `notifyAll()` not wake the waiting thread immediately?

Comment: The problem isn't obvious to me, but waiting in a constructor is generally a bad idea.  Indeed, that might be related to your problem if the Loader is trying to use an already-constructed MyPanel.

Comment: excellent point on the attempt to use a constructed `MyPanel`.  This actually raises another question about why I don't get a `NullPointerException` when trying to use it, as it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yep, the "calling" thread isn't given a chance to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have verified that execution passes through notifyAll() several times (usually >20) before the calling thread wakes up and displays the image in the frame.

Your loader thread is looping, *immediately* reacquiring the monitor on `caller.images`, probably before it gives up its timeslice.

The waiting thread has to reacquire the monitor before it can make progress - which it can't do because the loader has grabbed it again.

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here, but starting a new thread and then waiting *within a constructor* is generally a really bad idea. Heck, if you can't do anything at all until the first image has loaded, why not do that synchronously? That's what you're *effectively* doing anyway...

Comment: Not sure why you got a down vote, this is almost certainly what's happening and good advice about flow control.

Comment: Loading the first image synchronously was the point, and I was aware that this is effectively what is happening.  I added a `yield()` after the end of the `synchronized` block, which i thought would yield to the only other waiting thread, which is the caller that should pick up and display the image.  regardless of whether this is good practice, I'd like to know why it is occurring.

Comment: @ewok `yield` is a hint to the scheduler, you cannot actually effect your timeslice. Given your tight loop, you almost certainly re-obtain the lock before the scheduler changes contexts because it's expensive.

Comment: @JasonCoco makes sense.  Obviously this is awful form, but would adding a `Thread.sleep()` likely give MyPanel time to grab the lock before the second iteration in the Loader?

Comment: @ewok It's also worth mentioning that if you placed your `yield` call inside the `synchronized` block, you'll still own the monitor when you yield, so you'll do a pointless context switch, the other thread will have woken but be unable to take the monitor, you'll switch back to your original, yielded thread, and release and retake the monitor immediately.

Comment: @ewok I'd advise using a concurrent queue to marshal the loaded images back and forth. Barring that, some other construct like Kumar suggested. If you want to maintain this structure, you will have to do a wait-notify dance, so when you come out of your monitor, you should re-aquire it and `wait` before continuing the loop, then have your panel side `notify` when it's done displaying the image.

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

**1.** `wait()` will **immediately**, release the lock.

**2.** `notify() or notifyAll()` will **not immediately** release the lock, but will have it till the ending braces of the synchronized block is reached..

**3.** Use `CountDownLatch` in `java.util.concurrent package`, for your above mentioned purpose.

Comment: I think a concurrent queue might be better, as the loader finishes loading images, it can just stick them on the queue and then the panel can wait on the queue and display images as they come across.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion, but i personally prefer CountDownLatch, as i use it when i need to do few things before running the main process... like Game.. i collect the players' last score, his weapons, etc.. before starting the game.

Comment: Yeah, countdown latches are very useful, just for his example, he has an arbitrary number of possible images, and he probably wants to begin displaying each as soon as it's available. If he doesn't want that effect, he might as well just block in the panel display and wait for the files to load because you'll get the same result.

Comment: I implemented using a CountDownLatch and it seems to work perfectly every time.  however, as I clearly do not understand concurrency in Java as well as I thought I did, can you explain why using a CountDownLatch is forcing the context switchwhen a simple wait/notify was failing to do so?

Comment: CountDownLatch is from java.util.concurrent package, classes and interfaces over here are thread-safe, moreover CountDownLatch's main purpose is to be used for this.ie (Wait for certain process to be done, and let the countdown get decrement by 1, as its gets to zero, it start with the process after await() method.) I have given the example of game in my above comments.

Answer (score 4):

"a simple multithreaded algorithm" is an oxymoron. Threads are always hard. Use abstractions from java.util.concurrent (they are also hard, but with some thought they can be managable) unless your name is Brian Goetz.

The two big errors in your code are:

- first of all, it is possible that loaders gets hold of the lock before Swing does and that it will not give it back until it is finished (yes, it gives it up once in a while, but it is possible that it will grab it again)
- since your JPanel constructor is called in EDT (and if it is not, then you have an even bigger error), paintComponent WILL NOT BE CALLED UNTILL THE CONSTRUCTOR IS FINISHED (only one thing can be happening in Swing at once). So you will not achieve what you want anyway.

There is more, but if you fix the two above, the rest will be irrelevant.

I suggest that you delete the whole waiting thing and:

- make the list synchronized (using images = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()); );
- add a call caller.repaint() in the loader, instead of the images.notifyAll()

**update:** I just read in one of the comments that your intention was to actually stop the EDT until the first image is loaded. In such case, your whole aim is wrong: blocking EDT is a major mistake.